# How can I get emmet to recognize spaces inside a class name when expanding?

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

If I type
.myClass and press tab emmet expands this how it should...
but if I type
.myClass class2 it does not expand because there is a space.
How can I add two classes to a div with emmet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using a space, use a dot.

http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-workflow-mastering-emmet-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple classes using dot insted of space.

Like that:

```
.myClass.class2
```

The result shoud be:

```
<div class="myClass class2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Emmet don't allow spaces.
Second: Emmet uses normal CSS style, just add a dot before any class you need.

Emmet has more options, but with common CSS you can put tags, classes, id, attributes, etc.